# How can I check which of my conditions was true in the where attribute in sequelizejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
User.findOrCreate({
        where: User.sequelize.or({username: req.body.username}, {mail: req.body.mail}),
        defaults: {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password, mail: req.body.mail}
    })
    .then((user) => {
        if(!user[1]) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: 'User exists!',
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I check which of my conditions was true in the `where` attribute? I would compare the `user.username` with `req.body.username` but it's not in the scope.

Comment: Try to add them as custom properties to the result of the query. In SQL, I'd use additional columns in the `select`. That said, I'm wondering why you would need this.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I want to determine if username or mail exists in database to give the user feedback what is duplicated.

Comment: Why don't you use `User.find()`?

Comment: Try to create the handler (`(user) => ...`) before calling `User.findOrCreate()`. At that point, `req` should be visible. There, you can create a function which takes `req` and returns a new function that accepts `user` and has access to two local variables with the user name and email.